# javascript: create array based on array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have the following array:

```
var k = {
    a: 67576567,
    b: 567657,
    c: "some",
    d: [
        {src:"b", id:1},
        {src:"c", id:2},
        {src:"d", id:3}
    ]
};
```

I'm looking for a way to obtain the following array without using a for:

```
["b", "c", "d"]
```

I tried to use the filter function but it always return the entire object:

```
var filtered = k.d.filter(function(value) {
    return value.src;
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

You just used the wrong function. What you need is `Array.map`

```
var arr = k.d.map(function(value) {
    return value.src;
});
```

`Array.map` is used to iterate and output a new array based on the return value of the callback while `Array.filter` just filters the existent array on the supposed boolean value that will be returned in the callback.

Comment: @lolol :p glad to help you. :D